# Open pdf viewer at a certain line (forward-search) from within an .Rnw (Sweave) file

Tags: emacs, sweave, auctex

I am working with Ubuntu 12.04, Emacs 24, and the (pdf) viewer Okular 0.14. I would like to be able to open Okular (and jump to a specific line) from an `.Rnw` (Sweave) file. By using

```lisp
(setq TeX-view-program-list
      '(("Okular" "okular --unique %o#src:%n`pwd`/./%b")))
```

in `~/.emacs`, this already works for `.tex` files, even in multi-file projects, consisting of a `master.tex` and a chapter `chapter.tex`. By using `C-c C-v` (or `C-c C-c View`) one can then jump to the corresponding line (this feature is also known as forward-search).

I would like to have forward-search from within `.Rnw` files, too, where `chapter.tex` is replaced by `chapter.Rnw` (Sweave). With the above setup, however, `C-c C-c View` (executed from within `chapter.Rnw`) gives me `"Output file "chapter.pdf" does not exist."`. Clearly, `master.pdf` should have been opened.

I tried to set Local Variables in `chapter.Rnw` (this works for pure `.tex` documents on `C-c C-_`), but it seems to be ignored for `.Rnw` files in both senses: First, `C-c C-_` doesn't insert anything anymore and, second, on `C-c C-c`, still the wrong file `chapter.pdf` is tried being opened. On `C-c C-c View`, I see the actual call to which `%o`, `%n`, and `%b` ... expand:

```
okular --unique chapter.pdf#src:8`pwd`/./chapter.Rnw
```

If I manually replace `chapter.pdf` by `master.pdf`, then I can jump from `chapter.Rnw` to the corresponding line in `master.pdf`. So the command basically works, but it does not find the correct master file from within `.Rnw` files.

Here is a minimal example:

chapter.Rnw:

```
% patchDVI setup (see vignette)
\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}
<<echo=FALSE>>=
.TexRoot <- "master.tex" 
@

foo bar foo bar
\clearpage
<<hist, echo=TRUE, fig=true>>=
X <- rnorm(50, mean=20, sd = 3)
hist(X)
@
foo bar foo bar

%%% Local Variables:
%%% mode: latex
%%% TeX-master: "master.tex"
%%% End:
```

master.tex:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{Sweave}

\fvset{listparameters={\setlength{\topsep}{0pt}}}
\renewenvironment{Schunk}{\vspace{\topsep}}{\vspace{\topsep}}

\begin{document}

\input{chapter}

\end{document}

%%% Local Variables:
%%% mode: latex
%%% TeX-master: t
%%% End:
```

wrapper.Rnw:

```
% patchDVI setup (see vignette)
<<echo=FALSE>>=
.SweaveFiles <- c("chapter.Rnw") 
@
```

I compile it using `Rscript -e "patchDVI::SweavePDF('chapter.Rnw', encoding='utf8')"` (so using Duncan Murdoch's R package patchDVI to get syncronization with `.Rnw` files. One can also compile the whole project, just replace `chapter.Rnw` by `wrapper.Rnw`.

Comment: What are `.Rnw` files?  Do you edit these files in `latex-mode` (the one from AucTeX)?  If yes, did you set the `TeX-master` variable for these files (i.e. by file local variables)?

Comment: .Rnw files are R equivalents of .Snw files (I believe); see ?RweaveLatex. I added some more information plus a minimal example above. Hope this helps. I'll add some more things later.

Comment: Did you try `TeX-master: "master"`, i.e. omitting the extension?  Just a wild guess, since I don't have Emacs at hand to really dig into this issue.

Comment: I tried it, but it did not change the behavior of the problem.

Comment: Did you verify that `TeX-master` has the correct value?  Move the cursor to the `chapter.Rnw` buffer, and press `C-h v TeX-master`.  Does this show `"master"` as current buffer local value?  Btw, what tool do I need to build `.Rnw` files?  I'd like to try building myself with your files…

Comment: Its value is `nil` (this was expected to me, since `%o` in the Okular call does not have the correct value; indeed, since `TeX-master` is `nil`, `%o` is expanded to the current [base] file name, that's why Okular tries to open `chapter.pdf`). Concerning `.Rnw` files: You need `R` and the package `patchDVI` installed (see Duncan Murdoch's homepage). I'll add some more information above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `TeX-normal-mode` is lost in `.Rnw` files and thus forward search as for `.tex` documents is not working anymore. To keep `TeX-normal-mode`, use:

```
(add-hook 'noweb-select-doc-mode-hook
      '(lambda ()
         (unless (boundp 'in-noweb-select-doc-mode-hook)
           (let* ((in-noweb-select-doc-mode-hook t)
              (deactivate-mark))
         (TeX-normal-mode t)))))
```